# Is it possible to recover luks drive after OS reinstallation? With screwed up disk img

Tags: encryption, luks

Original layout of the drive was sda1 (766mb), sda5 (luks), Wasn't able to boot and stupidly reinstalled OS (Ubuntu 20.04). Before reinstalling I created a partition image of the luks drive, but after restoring the image elsewhere there is no data, should I have imaged LVM partition? After restoration of the luks partition it still asks for password, which works, but again no data.

Current disk info:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 117.45 GiB, 126097555456 bytes, 246284288 sectors
Disk model: [disk]
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbb610a29
```

Info from luksdump on image:

```
cryptsetup luksDump diskimg.img
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           eff2a9f0-4edb-460c-908a-4a3384b0246f
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
    offset: 16777216 [bytes]
    length: (whole device)
    cipher: aes-xts-plain64
    sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
    Key:        512 bits
    Priority:   normal
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
    Cipher key: 512 bits
    PBKDF:      argon2i
    Time cost:  4
    Memory:     1048576
    Threads:    4
    Salt:       98 f7 e4 14 9e 52 d0 1a 1f e6 ef b5 ba c6 70 cf 
                fc 59 a9 33 be 00 6c 9a cb 7c 9d 77 95 ef d5 eb 
    AF stripes: 4000
    AF hash:    sha256
    Area offset:32768 [bytes]
    Area length:258048 [bytes]
    Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
    Hash:       sha256
    Iterations: 121138
    Salt:       11 15 56 6a 9a 13 93 6b 81 2f b0 de c9 b7 09 ad 
                e6 fd e2 37 5c 72 3f 36 a0 3c 37 ee 51 b2 0b e7 
    Digest:     35 1e 86 8c 4f cf 6c 4b 77 ea e6 04 c4 cd 08 41 
                62 bb f9 d6 86 cf 91 12 d8 01 40 63 5d 61 8a dd
```

Hex dump of image:

```
sudo hexdump -C diskimg.img |grep LUKS 
[sudo] password for user: 
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00  |LUKS..........@.|
```

Sorry for my lack of knowledge but can this be salvaged? Not sure if the original drive info is overwritten or if the disk image is any help.

Thanks.

Edit:

Ok, so when I imaged the drive it was unlocked and I only imaged the luks partition (IE. only the luks part of the drive and not the unlocked part of the drive), now when restored I cannot mount the drive - "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock". Is this salvageable?

I've tried imaging to a separate drive, losetup, mount, mounting the image,etc., everything comes up with errors. When I unlock the drive I can open the drive, (input password) but any attempts to mount it will result in errors. I've even tried to DD the unlocked partition to another drive, no luck.

Is this in any way salvageable?

Thanks.

Comment: If you wrote over an encrypted volume, I doubt you will be able to recover anything. Restore from your backups.

Comment: I would be surprised if the data section is overwritten, but the header still intact. Your description is a little vague. When you say "it asks for password", where and when does it do that, and what is "it"? Make sure you know where the image is mounted when you open your image with cryptsetup.

Comment: I restored the image to another partition on another drive but when i unlock the volume there's no data in it. I was supposed to image the luks part of the drive, right? I don't really see how I imaged an empty drive. I've unlocked it with disks utility, lukscrypt... nothing.

Comment: Ok, so the drive was unlocked when I imaged the luks drive (was this a mistake?), now when restored I cannot mount the drive - "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock". Is this screwed?